# XCode6 Formatting the code

Tags: xcode, format

Have any method can formatting the code?

I want to set hotkey in xcode6(like eclipse command + shift + f).

Have anyone know how to setting in xcode 6 for objective-c and swift?

(sorry my question description is so short. but I just want to know where is this about setting)

In xcode6 , I had go to edit->format , but I don't know which one .

thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format code use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> for format the selected code.

You change this hotkey bij going to the keybindings setting page ad search for `Structure > Re-Ident` under Editor Menu for Data Model Comperison.

Comment: Selecting it and pressing CMD + X, CMD + V also seems to correct indents.

Comment: Our just selected that code and press ctrl+i. There is not need to copy past it.

Comment: Of course you're right, but if he ever forgets THAT shortcut, he can just repaste and not waste time finding the correct combination.

Comment: Can I change the hotkey ? I browse the preference , I was not found ctrl+i. thank you very much